# How to prevent specifying decoding on read_csv from changing datetime precision

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I have had to type notes manually in a dataframe, and am now trying to read it back in to sort it. When I tried to read it in normally, I get an error which states `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 28: invalid start byte`

I was able to resolve this by passing `encoding='cp1252'` to my `pd.read_csv()`  line, and it read in the file properly for the most part.
However, the seconds value of my datetimes were all cut off due to this. Are there any suggestions for how to maintain precision when passing the encoding instruction?

So my date: `2019-11-09 11:57:13` will just show up as `2019-11-09 11:57` and I need the extra precision to remain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe it is not problem with data in DataFrame but in method which it use to display it - and maybe if you manually display it then you get correct value.

Comment: I've tried that unfortunately, when I send it to a new csv file, it ends up with 00 values for the seconds for each time

Comment: it is unusuall behavior - maybe add original file (as link to Google Drive, Dropbox or similar place) and code which you use - then we can test this problem.